# What is the difference between a Markov process and a Markov chain?

Tags: probability, markov-chains, markov-process

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between all types of Markov Chains?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22982/what-is-the-difference-between-all-types-of-markov-chains)

I've read a lot about Markov processes and chains but so far I don't understand what the difference is between the two. Is there any difference?

Comment: I know some people take them to be the same thing, however, according to Wikipedia a Markov chain is traditionally taken to mean a discrete Markov process.

Comment: I agree. I've only encountered the term Markov chain when both the time-parameter space and state space is countable.

Comment: This was asked recently on the site.

Comment: I've a similar point on [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3902/tags-markov-process-and-markov-chains) some time ago

Comment: duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/22982